# Table View not adjusting to orientation rotation properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a Table View inside of my View, The table view is set to "Scale to Fill" which is how I have been working with these in the past without issue. The problem is that this time around when I have the table view loaded up in portrait mode, it looks and behaves just like a table view should, but when the orientation is rotated to landscape this is what I see:

[image]

Instead of the list behaving as it normally would its sticking to a portrait orientation that can still be scrolled, but portrait nevertheless. I need this table to fill around the perimeter of the green box.

I have tried setting the mode to : "Aspect Fit" and "Aspect fill" in storyboards but no luck so far.

How can i fix this issue? **Please be as detailed as possible.**

Comment: Why do you have a table view inside a view?

Comment: Add the time it seemed like the best option considering I was going to have other content on screen as well, can this be causing the issue? something to look at when I get back to work on the project today @JFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simply overlooked my autosizing settings for the table view.